# Multiple setState inside componentDidMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, render, setstate

Is it possible to have multiple `setState` inside `componentDidMount()`?

I have this structure of code and each of console logs is actually giving me the correct values.

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      index : 0,
      index2 : 0
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(url)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {

        // 1st setState
        var index = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          //somecode
        }
        this.setState({ index : index});
        console.log("this.state.index" , this.state.index); // value: 1

        // 2nd setState
        var index = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          //somecode
        }
        this.setState({ index2 : index});
        console.log("this.state.index2" , this.state.index2); // value: 2
      })
  }

  render() {
    value1={this.state.index}
    value2={this.state.index2}
  }
```

However, when I call it inside `render()`, it seems thats is still using the initial values set in the constructor.

How to deal with this approach? Thanks!

Comment: each of them is triggering rerender, so that is an antipattern. You better pack them in one single `setState`

Comment: what do you want to achieve with this flow?

Comment: Already got an answer below. Thanks again!

Comment: Goodluck to me! someone just gives this a negative vote, as a beginner in Javascript, I think its good to know things better by asking questions that is so specific and great I got an answer :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is no issue in using multiple `setState` but it is not recomended because it will trigger render everytime. Inspite you can use one `setState` at the end of `componentDidMount`.

for example:

```
componentDidMount() {
fetch(url)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {

    // 1st setState
    var index = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      //somecode
    }
    //this.setState({ index : index});
    console.log("this.state.index" , this.state.index);

    // 2nd setState
    var index = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      //somecode
    }
    //this.setState({ index2 : index});
    this.setState({
      index,
      index2: index,
      key1: value1,
    })
    console.log("this.state.index2" , this.state.index2);
  })
}
```

Comment: Ahhh! I got it! It works like a charm :) Thank you so much!